# LinkedIn share button does not share the exact post

Tags: linkedin-api

Below is my LinkedIn share button. I am trying to share a youtube video on linkedIn. But it does not share the exact video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDVzjn9s9E) on LinkedIn instead it always shares the default youtube home page(https://www.youtube.com/). Does LinkedIn accept only embedded URL or it does not accept the URL which contains id? Please suggest the solution.

```
  <li>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wDVzjn9s9E" style="color: white;">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to URL-encode the URL you want to share?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their `/shareArticle` endpoint ignores query string parameters.

The official share url for the video you YouTube is `https://youtu.be/4wDVzjn9s9E` and `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://youtu.be/4wDVzjn9s9E` seems to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks. Suppose If want to share something like this https://www.progress.com/auto/main.asp?id=@Model.id. How do I get the url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to do [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with parameters you are feeding to another URL.  So, your link should be `...&url=https%3A%2F%2Fw...`, and not `...&url=https://`.  Your URL also contains a question mark that should be escaped.  Ultimately, your URL should look like this..

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4wDVzjn9s9E
```

Works for me!  Interesting video there about Lionel. =)

[image]

In case you want to know more: **[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**